# gcutil does not show images or kernels

Tags: google-compute-engine

The gcutil tool for google compute engine does not show any images/kernels in the list subcommand as:

```
$ gcutil listimages --project <project_name>
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+
| name | description | creation-time | kernel |
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+
+------+-------------+---------------+--------+
```

Although if we don't specify a image while provisioning a instance it provides the set of image options:

```
$ gcutil addinstance cj-test-001

1: projects/google/global/images/centos-6-2-v20120326
2: projects/google/global/images/centos-6-2-v20120503
3: projects/google/global/images/centos-6-2-v20120611
4: projects/google/global/images/centos-6-2-v20120621
...
22: projects/google/global/images/ubuntu-12-04-v20120611
23: projects/google/global/images/ubuntu-12-04-v20120621
24: projects/google/global/images/ubuntu-12-04-v20120912
```

How do i fix the problem of listing images via gcutil?

Answer (score 5):

By default the `gcutil listimages` command lists the custom images for a project.

To list the default images provided by Google, run this command:

```
$ gcutil --project=google listimages
```

More details in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images